# What's the secret to getting ClaimsResponse working with DotNetOpenId?

Tags: .net, asp.net, security, openid, dotnetopenauth

What's the secret to getting ClaimsResponse working with [DotNetOpenId](http://code.google.com/p/dotnetopenid/)?

For example, in this bit of code (from [Scott Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CategoryView.aspx?category=DasBlog)) the ClaimsResponse object should have lots of nice little things like 'nickname' and 'email address', but the ClaimsResponse object itself is 'null':

```
 OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();  
 if (openid.Response != null)  
 {  
    // Stage 3: OpenID Provider sending assertion response  
    switch (openid.Response.Status)  
    {  
       case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:  
          ClaimsResponse fetch = openid.Response.GetExtension(typeof(ClaimsResponse)) as ClaimsResponse;  
          string nick = fetch.Nickname;  
          string homepage = openid.Response.ClaimedIdentifier;  
          string email = fetch.Email;  
          string comment = Session["pendingComment"] as string;  
          string entryId = Session["pendingEntryId"] as string;  
          if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(comment) == false && String.IsNullOrEmpty(entryId) == false)  
          {  
             AddNewComment(nick, email, homepage, comment, entryId, true);  
          }  
          break;  
    }  
 }
```

At first, I thought it was because I wasn't redirecting to the provider with a 'ClaimsRequest' ... but using this code to redirect to the OpenId provider still doesn't help:

```
OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();  
IAuthenticationRequest req = openid.CreateRequest(openid_identifier.Text);  
ClaimsRequest fetch = new ClaimsRequest();  
fetch.Email = DemandLevel.Require;  
fetch.Nickname = DemandLevel.Require;  
req.AddExtension(fetch);  
req.RedirectToProvider();
```

What am I doing wrong?  Or have other devs experienced the same pain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks fine.  But be aware that the sreg extension, which you are using, isn't supported by all OPs.  If the OP you're authenticating with doesn't support it, then the response extension will be null as you're seeing.  So a null check is always a good idea.

myopenid.com supports sreg, if you're looking for an OP to test against.

Answer (score 6):

I dont know if you have solved the problem or not, but I found the solution after many hours of struggle. Actually you need to change your web.config file to claim email and fullname 
here is web.config which works for me. I downloaded it from nerddinner project. Actually  I copied everything except web.config and I was not getting the email field. So later on I found something else is wrong. I copied web.config from nerddinner project and everything was working.

here is the file, if you dont want to go to nerddinner project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- 
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
     </sectionGroup>
    <section name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.config">
  </connectionStrings>
  <dotNetOpenAuth>
    <openid>
      <relyingParty>
        <behaviors>
          <add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform, DotNetOpenAuth" />
        </behaviors>
      </relyingParty>
    </openid>
  </dotNetOpenAuth>
  <system.web>
    <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
    -->
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Logon" />
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="/Dinners/Trouble">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Dinners/Confused" />
    </customErrors>

    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Globalization" />
        <add namespace="System.Linq" />
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*.mvc" validate="false" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
    </httpModules>
    <trace enabled="true" requestLimit="10" pageOutput="false" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
  -->
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="MvcHttpHandler" />
      <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler" />
      <add name="MvcHttpHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="*.mvc" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="microsoft.visualstudio.teamsystems.backupinfo" value="8;web.config.backup" />
    <!-- Fill in your various consumer keys and secrets here to make the sample work. -->
    <!-- You must get these values by signing up with each individual service provider. -->
    <!-- Twitter sign-up: https://twitter.com/oauth_clients -->
    <add key="twitterConsumerKey" value="" />
    <add key="twitterConsumerSecret" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Ahh -- thanks for the info.  Looks like the magic line might be the DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform line ... see http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/the-axfetchassregtransform-behavior/

Answer (score 2):

With the latests version of DotNetOpenId, this code seems to work fine for me:

```
var request = openid.CreateRequest(openid_identifier);
var fields = new ClaimsRequest();
fields.Email = DemandLevel.Require;
fields.Nickname = DemandLevel.Require;
request.AddExtension(fields);
request.RedirectToProvider();
```

on return from provider:

```
var claimResponse = openid.Response.GetExtension<ClaimsResponse>();
```

PS: I'm using MVC, not WebForms.

Comment: I'm really curious -- what OpenId provider are you using?

Comment: same as you mate, DotNetOpenId.

Comment: No no -- I mean when you connect to validate your OpenId; are you using Yahoo, AOL, Wordpress, MyOpenId, etc?

Comment: I am able to validate against MyOpenId and Verisign labs in my testing. It should work fine with any openID provider.

Answer (score 2):

I used

```
   /* worked */var fetch = new FetchRequest();
   fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
   request.AddExtension(fetch);
```

instead of

```
   /* didnt work*/
   var fields = new ClaimsRequest();
   fields.Email = DemandLevel.Require;
   fields.FullName = DemandLevel.Require;
   request.AddExtension(fields);
```

And in the response try

```
    this.Request.Params["openid.ext1.value.alias1"];
```

simply instead of accessing the claims. This worked with me in the ASP.Net for google.

The issue in ASP.Net is that the request is not sent complete when using ClaimsRequest you can see that if you used Fiddler. and the response is also not retrieved correctly to you need to access direct paramaters from the Request.params they are all there.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me (using PayPal Access as a identifier) in C#

The below worked for me:

```
OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var response = openid.GetResponse();

    if (response != null)
    {
        switch (response.Status)
        {
            case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:

                if (this.Request.Params["openid.ext1.value.alias1"] != null)
                {
                    Response.Write(this.Request.Params["openid.ext1.value.alias1"]);
                    Response.Write(this.Request.Params["openid.ext1.value.alias2"]);
                }
                else {
                    Response.Write("Alias wrong");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
 protected void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var openidRequest = openid.CreateRequest(openIdBox.Text);
    var fetch = new FetchRequest();

    fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
    fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.FullName);
    openidRequest.AddExtension(fetch);

    openidRequest.RedirectToProvider();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could receive parameters correctly after the following updated in web.config that I copied from a sample.

```
<section name="dotNetOpenAuth"
         type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection"
         requirePermission="false" 
         allowLocation="true"/>
```

under  `<configsections>`

and add these alone

```
<dotNetOpenAuth>
    <openid>
        <relyingParty>
            <behaviors>
                <add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform, DotNetOpenAuth"/>
            </behaviors>
        </relyingParty>
    </openid>
</dotNetOpenAuth>
```